# Adding field from foreign key in django-tasypie ToOneField

Tags: python, django

When using django-tasypie is there a way one can add an extra field form the related object apart from the resource url?

I have an Album model and a Photo model.

```
class Album(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(_('Album Name'), max_length=250, default=_('Untitled Album'))

class Photo(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album)
```

I have these as ModelResources in the api:

```
class PhotoResource(ModelResource):
    album = fields.ToOneField('ampwefly.apps.photos.api.AlbumResource', 'album')

class AlbumResource(ModelResource):
    photo = fields.ToManyField(PhotoResource, 'photo_set', related_name='photo', full=True)
```

As it stands I am able to return the following when I access the url of a single photo:

```
{
    album: "/api/v1/album/2/",
    description: "",
    id: "1",
    image: "/uploads/uploads/users/images/e-jey.jpg",
    resource_uri: "/api/v1/photo/1/",
    uploaded: "2012-11-22T22:42:26.051779"
}
```

If I use:

```
album = fields.ToOneField('ampwefly.apps.photos.api.AlbumResource', 'album', full=True)
```

This will return all the fields of the album but what I would like to try to do is return on the title in addition to the the Resource url such as:

```
{
    album: {
        id: "2",
        resource_uri: "/api/v1/album/2/",
        title: "Untitled Album"
    },
    description: "",
    id: "1",
    image: "/uploads/uploads/users/images/e-jey.jpg",
    resource_uri: "/api/v1/photo/1/",
    uploaded: "2012-11-22T22:42:26.051779"
}
```

What would be a suggested solution to get the result above?